# showdialog - wpf image does not change in mainwindow

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, showdialog

In my mainWindow bitmap change (set new source) works fine.
But if I create a new window with ShowDialog, all changes affects (e.g. ListView, Textbox values e.g.) in the Mainwindow.

Bitmap (I set the new source) doesn't.
What can I do?

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
image.BeginInit();                    
image.UriSource = new Uri(filename, UriKind.Relative);
image.EndInit();
imgError.Source = null;
imgError.Source = image;
```

In my MainWindow.xaml I use an image:

```
<Image x:Name="imgError" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="imgError_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"  Source="circle_blue_Error.png"  Visibility="Visible"  Width="50" Height="50" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="28" />
```

If an error occurs, a TextBox.Text is set with a number. TextBox_Changed Event set imgError to an other image, a ListView(log) becomes new Item. Everything works fine.

When I open a new Window in DialogMode (set some parameters) and an error occures (child window is open) Textbox Value and ListView changes, imgError is set but the UI doesn't change.

```
SetRoll frmSetRoll = new SetRoll();          

//for positioning
frmSetRoll.wndParent = this;
frmSetRoll.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Where do you execute this code? Before creating the window? Some handler of the window you show? Who is imgError? Please provide more of the source code, it is impossible to understand the structure of your code from what you've provided.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/486 and pay attention to the section about `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel`. It may help you finding the problem if it is binding related. In some cases, binding to `null` brings unexpected results.

Comment: I have found the problem, Textbox receive value twice.

Answer (score -1):

I have found the problem, TextBox receives value twice.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not helpful for anyone who has a similar problem and finds your question/answer